# Stopping a YouTube video after exiting a lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

To begin, I am a newbie to javascript. I've read other StackOverflow document ions to assist me with my dilemma. Simply put, I want to pause or stop a YouTube video once the user exits the lightbox.

I found this lightbox online (https://codepen.io/Jake_Leggett/pen/wxqht) and am using it with this site (http://thesupersustainables.com/beta). The items I have found mostly reference jQuery and when using the code it doesn;t seem to work what what I've found. I did add the YouTube API, but noticed it works with targeting one video and I am working with multiple videos in different sections of the site.

This is what I used so far:

```
        var curr_lb_div;
        var is_modal = false;
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        //youtube api
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        function ShowLightBox(lb_div, isModal) {
        document.getElementById(lb_div).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        curr_lb_div = lb_div;
         if (isModal)
             is_modal = true;
         else is_modal = false;

         setCenter(lb_div, isModal);
         //setDimensions(lb_div);
        }

        function HideLightBox() {
            if (document.getElementById(curr_lb_div)) {
                  document.getElementById(curr_lb_div).style.display='none';
                  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
                  curr_lb_div = '';
             }
        }

        function setCenter(lb_div, isModal) {
        var div = document.getElementById(lb_div);

        var newX = div.offsetWidth / 2;
        var newY = div.offsetHeight / 2;

        div.style.marginLeft = '-'+newX+'px';
        div.style.marginTop = '-'+newY+'px';

        }
```

X

WATCH THE VIDEO